# Issues in copying files on iOS using NSStreams

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, macos, file-copying

I am trying to copy image and media files using `NSStreams`. I can not use `NSFileManager` `copyItemAtPath`, as I have to copy the file using streams.

The data is transferred over the network and the stream is read by a Python script that writes the data to a file. This worked fine on Mac OSX but when I tried in iOS,the file was not saved in the proper format.

I am able to copy all the files, but some of the **metadata** like **dimensions** (for image  and media files), and **duration** (for media files) is missing in the copied file, and the **kind** is always **Document**. The other metadata is fine.

When I try to read the file attributes using the **NSFileManager**

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"filePath" error:&error];
```

It shows an error in the console:

> The operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory

I also observed that all the copied files, irrespective of the file extension (.png,.jpeg,.mov, .zip), has a **kind** of **Document**

How do I copy the source image metadata into the copied file?

Are there any Xcode optimizations I need to turn off?

- OS    : Mac OSX 10.8.4, iOS 6
- Xcode : 4.6.3

Comment: Why do you want to use NSStream? An NSStream object can only represent the data fork of a file, which is not good enough and is sometimes empty for files that contain gigabytes of data elsewhere in the file. Trying to implement this yourself is a mistake, the correct way to copy a file has changed many times over the last few years. Best to tell the kernel to do the file copy, using NSFileManager. There are lower level options if you need extra flexibility. FSCopyObjectAsync() for example.

Comment: Do you know how spotlight works? Core Storage? iCloud syncing? Resource Forks? ACL permissions? Time Machine? Kqueue notifications? Hard Link directories? What about unknown changes that might come in the 2014 release of OS X? You need to know all if this to copy a file.

Comment: Where does Python come into this?

Comment: Maybe I'm totally off with this suggestion but if you experience behavioral differences of the same code between iOS and OSX, make sure the file name you are trying to open is correct case-wise. The OSX filesystem is case-INSENSITIVE most of the time while the one on your iOS device is always case-SENSITIVE. (The simulator obviously behaves the same way as the host it runs on.) I repeatedly bump into this flaw, it might be your case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is an issue with file extension.Some junk characters appended after the file extension( something like 1.png\\\)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for any type of file:

```
if (![NSFileManager.defaultManager copyItemAtPath: sourceFileName toPath: targetFileName error: &error]) {
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithError: error];
    [alert runModal];
    return;
}
```